# correct way of cooking

Tags: grammaticality

What is correct

Sometimes I cook for myself

or

Sometimes I cook myself.

This sounds like cooking self, which is not true. I've heard ( most of times ) people use second phrase. Which of the two is correct ?.

Comment: Look for yourself, there's a previous post on ELU on this, I am quite certain.

Comment: When you cook yourself, you don't cook **your self,** you do it **by** yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct but with slightly different meaning.

*Sometimes I cook for myself* implies that usually you eat meals prepared for you by other people.

*Sometimes I cook myself* implies that you usually do not prepare meals.

Comment: sorry for delayed response but, "cooking for myself" means eat meals cooked by self. "cook myself" sounds like cook self, which sounds incorrect "technically" speaking.

Answer (score 0):

The former is certainly correct.

The latter is incorrect - it is ambiguous and redundant.

Comment: It would take Tommy Cooper to make the second sentence sound ambiguous. In speech, stress patterns remove all hint of ambiguity. The 'myself' is not redundant; it's there to emphasise. It's standard usage; doubtless the canonical structure is _Sometimes I myself cook_, but most people would shun this to avoid sounding like Jeeves in the 1930s. Chenmunka gives the correct answer.

Comment: The second version is likely to be unambiguous when spoken, but can easily be misinterpreted in its written form.